# JQuery data attribute selector undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with data attributes in some basic html and javascript. I have several links throughout a page that dynamically insert a map and a 'close' link to get rid of the map.

The links are all similar to:

```
<a class="maplocation" href="#" data-coords="4645/234234" data-zoom="9">Link text<span class="mapslideicon"></span></a>
```

And the javascript on clicking these links is:

```
$("a.maplocation").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("mapopen") == true) {
        // Map already clicked and open, do nothing
    } else {
        var timeStamp = $.now();
        var mapID = "m_"+timeStamp;
        var mapCloseID = "c_"+timeStamp;
        var anchorID = "a_"+timeStamp;
        var mapClass = 'widemap';
        var mapDiv = $("<div class='"+mapClass+"' id='"+mapID+"'>&nbsp;</div><a href='#' id='"+mapCloseID+"' class='maplocationclose'>close</a>");
            mapDiv.insertAfter($(this).parent());
        // Set a data attribute on the link to let it know a map is open
        $(this).data( "mapopen", true );
        // Set a data attribute on the link so that we can reference it from the close button
        $(this).data( "anchorid", anchorID );
    }
    return false;
});
```

This creates a div for a map, places a data attribute on the original anchor to say that the map is open and also creates an anchor for closing the map.

When the close map anchor is clicked it executes the following:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.maplocationclose', function(){ // delegated.
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        idNo = id.split("_");
        var assocMapID = "m_"+idNo[1];
        var assocAnchorID = "a_"+idNo[1];
        $("#"+id).remove();
        $("#"+assocMapID).slideUp( 300, function() {
            $("#"+assocMapID).remove();
        });
    // Set a data elemt on the original map link that let's us know the map is closed again
    $('.maplocation[anchorid="'+assocAnchorID+'"]').data( "mapopen", false );
    return false;
});
```

This all works but I'm having difficulty in accessing the data-attribute from the close anchor. It references fine from the original link, as I intended, and sets the mapped attribute as true and reads it as true. However, when I set it to false in the close anchor it cannot find it and it's never set.

I've run a test (from inside the maplocationclose function) to see if I can find any data attributes from the anchor, such as:

```
console.log("Zoom Attr is: " + $('a.maplocation[anchorid="'+assocAnchorID+'"]').data('zoom'));
```

And they're returning 'undefined'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attaching data using `.data()` does not add/alter any `data-*` attributes, hence your attribute selector won't match anything.

You can use filter instead though:

```
$('.maplocation').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('anchorid') == assocAnchorID;
}).data( "mapopen", false );
```

Comment: And even if it _did_ work (as it does for actual attributes), it would be `$('.maplocation[data-anchorid="'+assocAnchorID+'"]')...`

Comment: @Mackan That's worth noting i guess, yes.

Comment: I'm getting my head around this, so excuse any mistakes, but perhaps I moved focus from the issue on hand with my `console.log` example. If that part is a mistake, using `data-*` attributes, I will correct it, though probably should have left it out of this example. My issue is with setting the `mapopen` attribute from the `maplocationclose` function and it doing nothing. I believed that I was exclusively using data caching for my `mapopen` attribute. Does your reason still apply? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @biscuitstack Sorry I'm not entirely sure what you are asking?

Comment: (Nevertheless I should mention that your suggestion does work, thank you. I'm just trying to better understand the problem and realise my issue is still there if I omit the `data-* attribute`s from my example along with the `console.log` test that refers to them. I'm wondering if they are a separate mistake, that you mention above, or if your explanation also applies to my main issue?)

Comment: It works as so: `data-*` attributes are parsed by jQuery script on page load, and attached using `.data()`. It's a one way system though, as attaching data using `.data()` does not populate a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: That was my understanding. So my confusion is in that I attached the `mapopen` attribute using .data() and never had it as a `data-*` attribute. I was never trying to alter any of the initial data attributes, just adding a new one using `.data()`. I understand your explanation in reference to my `console.log` call which reference a `data-*` attribute named 'zoom' but not to my selectors which reference `anchorid` and `mapopen` that were added only with `.data()` with no attempt to reference or change any of the `data-*' attributes.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if I defined that my understanding of `data-*` attributes in my example are all the ones I wrote in the html and never referenced again but for my call to `console.log`. Maybe I'm wrong on that one.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your use of the `data` method @biscuitstack. It's that you can't use the selector like you did, since no such attribute (`anchorid`) exist on the element. There is an `data-anchorid` (or similar) in the DOM, but it's never added to the element like using `.attr('data-anchorid', 'myval')` would behave.

Comment: Which begs my question of how it is not attached to the element if I can set it and `mapopen` in my `a.maplocation` click function and correctly return a boolean for the status of `mapopen` in the same function when checked later? Is it that `$(this)` is not referring to the anchor element in the way I imagine?

Comment: @biscuitstack It is attached, but not directly on the element. jQuerys `data()` manipulates and reads from the DOM/node tree, not the html elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: And this is where I'm out of my depth and need to go and read up on this some more. Thanks for your patience with explanations Mackan and George.

Answer (score 1):

*Just to expand on the comments following @Georges answer.*

Your code that is causing issues:

```
$('.maplocation[anchorid="'+assocAnchorID+'"]').data( "mapopen", false );
```

Now, first of all the syntax for this selector is wrong. Even if you have a data attribute named `anchorid` on an element, that is not how you would retrieve it. You should include the *data-* part; `data-anchorid`.

Check the below example, and the console output, to understand why it is failing:

```
<div class="maplocation" data-anchorid="25" data-test="works">...</div>  

var x = $('.maplocation[anchorid="25"]');
var y = $('.maplocation[data-anchorid="25"]');
console.log('Length of x: ' + x.length) //This is 0, because element x does not exist
console.log('Length of y: ' + y.length) //1
console.log('Value of x: ' + x.data('test')) //This is undefined because element x does not exist
console.log('Value of y: ' + y.data('test')) //works
```

But, that doesn't solve the issue, since you have no attribute on the actual element you can't use that selector either. `data()` is not writing to the element, like `attr()` does, but instead it only adds the keys/values to the jQuery internal collection/cache.

jQuery docs on `data()`:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

jQuery docs on `attr()`:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

See this for an illustration:

```
$('.maplocation').data('mydata','myvalue'); //Only added to jQuery collection/internal cache, not DOM/element
console.log($('.maplocation[data-mydata="myvalue"]').data('test')) //undefined
$('.maplocation').attr('data-mydata','myvalue'); //Added to DOM/element
console.log($('.maplocation[data-mydata="myvalue"]').attr('data-test')) //works
```

**Solutions**
So, the solution provided by George will work since it will get a collection of all elements with `.maplocation` and then filter that to only return the one that has a `.data('anchorid') == assocAnchorID`.

Other options:

- You can use `attr()` instead of `data()` for setting/getting. Everything will be treated as strings, so you'll have to modify the code accordingly, and remember to include *'data-'* when using it (example: `data('test')` should be `attr('data-test')`). Example:

  ```
  $('.maplocation[data-anchorid="'+assocAnchorID+'"]').attr( "data-mapopen", "false" );
  ```
- You can use another selector to get the element, then use `data()` as normal. This is just an example as I don't know if `closest` will work with your structure:

  ```
  $(this).closest('.maplocation').data( "mapopen", false );
  ```

Comment: Much appreciated that you took the time to add this extra specific followup Mackan. What you've written pretty much makes sense to me now other than contradicting bits and pieces I'd read before resorting to asking for help here. Either there's a lot of misinformation on `.data()` out there or I'm worse at selective reading than I thought ;) Either way, yours and @George examples solved the issue and gave nice clarity in the sea of information on the subject (there's plenty of similar posts to this, as I'm sure you're aware). Thanks again.

Comment: @biscuitstack I posted it to help, obviously, but I also have a secondary goal: To test my own knowledge and see if I can explain it as well as I hope, and if my understanding and examples hold up :) As you say there are plenty of similar info about, so I will probably not leave this up. I gained some knowledge while writing this mess, so it's a win-win ;) Think of `data()` as `prop()`, both compared to `attr()`.

Comment: I would leave it up. Honestly, I do my homework before asking a question here. I had read through and trialled many similar questions and solutions on this that left me stumped. I don't come from a programming background and none of the explanations I found quite hit the nail on the head for those coming from a different angle, as accurate or not as they were. This thorough explanation compliments my (persistent!) questions and is useful to anyone Googling for more detail on the matter.